# Whose helmet and jeep were found out in the forest?

Tags: jurassic-park, jurassic-world

While on the run, Gray and Zach come across a helmet with a claw rip and a crashed Jeep. (I recall the Jeep being a roofless blue Jeep, matching the color scheme of the new Jurassic World park).

The Jeep is found away from the main park,

> not too far from the ruins of the original park.

**Whose helmet/Jeep did they find?**

(note: I don't expect anyone to be able to identify them by name - even just "one of this group of staff" sort of answer is fine)

Comment: Dennis Nedrys Jeep from the first movie ? That wasn't roofless however (and I can't tell from the youtube clips if that was blue, and obviously it would not match the Jurassic World color scheme). I haven't seen Jurassic World, but that would be a nice nod to the first movie.

Comment: @EikePierstorff Nedry's was my first thought too, but I can't find any photos of blue jeeps from the first movie, and [Nedry's Jeep had the normal beige/red scheme](https://www.screenused.com/images/auction_nov13/14024_7.jpg).

Comment: Personally I assumed it was from a member of the ACU (Asset Containment Unit?) they sent out, but that may have been an incorrect assumption. Definitely seemed like it was from the new Jurassic World rather than the original Jurassic Park.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Certainly possible, but I was under the impression that most of the ACU hadn't gotten out that far.

Comment: It looked to me like the wreck and blood were fairly recent.  I assumed that it had not been ACU (they had much cooler vehicles) personnel, but just normal park personnel out doing a round or some such.  I figured distance to the original park were inconsequential, especially since no jeeps were missing when the kids got there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the film's [official novelisation](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0553536907) (based on the original screenplay), the jeep and helmet evidently belong to one of Jurassic World's maintenance crews:

> The brothers ran down the road, but soon the tracks veered off into
>   the vegetation. Worried, Zach and Gray followed the path of broken
>   tree limbs down a hill until **they came to a Jurassic World maintenance
>   vehicle that had crashed into a rock wall.**
>
> The boys cautiously approached the vehicle. Zach peered through the
>   shattered windshield. No one was inside. The driver’s seat was ripped,
>   its white stuffing stained with blood. Zach backed away, realizing
>   what had probably clawed the driver out of the vehicle.
>
> “Who did it?” Gray asked. “The white one?”
>
> Zach took his brother’s arm. “We shouldn’t stay here.”

Comment: Found yourself a new novelisation, have you? :-)

Comment: @randal'thor - Had it for ages. But just watched the film yesterday.